# Cannot do a VBA to lookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Need help to VBA code a vlookup, trying to get the name of sales rep from the client account number cell that is bellow the "account number" text.

Need to VLOOKUP on a different sheet to return KAM name to "A2" based on client account number "B2".

Can someone help with challenge please? Thank you in advanced.

```
     "column A"         "column B"
ROW1   KAM          Customer account
ROW2                    10002
ROW3                    Date
ROW4                    13/02/2019
ROW5                    Currency
ROW6    
ROW7                    Customer account
                    10003
                    Date
                    29/08/2019
                    30/08/2019
                    12/09/2019
                    18/09/2019
                    25/09/2019
                    27/09/2019
                    Currency
```

Comment: Where is the code you have tried, and what problems did you have with it? We aren't here to just write all the code for you.

Comment: yes, you're right - not what i intended. But tried so many code lines and never got anywhere. Honestly, since i need to lookup the number that is always below the text "costumer account" don't even know where to start. But will start again to write and get back to check any errors. Thank you so much for helping

Comment: Can you please check? Getting syntax error. Sheets("RAW DATA FILE).RANGE("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(C2),INDEX(Sheet2!C,MATCH(Sheet1!C[1],Sheet2!C[2],0)),""""),"""")"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A50000")
    Range("A1:A5").Select

Comment: I still don't understand the question properly. Why do you want to use VBA? What exactly are you trying to do with the code above?

Comment: trying to get the name of the KAM for each client account number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Find` and `Offset` method to lookup the name in this type of datasheet. Following is the samplecode for your reference:

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("B:B").Find("10002")
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
MsgBox Rng.Offset(-1, -1)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. I have the below that gives me error "COMPILE ERROR: SYBTAX ERROR".

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but instead of using `VLOOKUP` you should be able to get your result using `INDEX` and `MATCH` instead (without using `VBA`). Try the following formula: `INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH("Customer account",Sheet1!$B:$B,0))`. This will return "KAM" to the cell you enter the formula into.

UPDATE:

Following your comments, the below will replicate what you are trying to do:

```
Dim OutputRange As Range
Set OutputRange = Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("A1:A50000")
OutputRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(C2),INDEX(Sheet2!C,MATCH(Sheet1!C[1],Sheet2!C[2],0)),""""),"""")"
```

Comment: I have done INDEX MAtch but gives me syntax error on 1st line, please check below

Comment: Sheets("RAW DATA FILE).RANGE("a:a").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(C2),INDEX(Sheet2!C,MATCH(Sheet1!C[1],Sheet2!C[2],0)),""""),"""")"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A50000")
    Range("A1:A5").Select

Comment: You are missing a `"` after the RAW DATA FILE string. It looks like you are just trying to insert an `INDEX/MATCH` formula in the first 50000 rows. Why are you using VBA for that?

Comment: now gives error: "run-time error '9': sunscript out of range"

Comment: Using VBA since have code to add new column, delete a few columns and rows and then get the name of KAM for the client account number

Comment: @BrunoFerreira does the code in the updated answer work?

Comment: I have changed the code for the actual sheet names and index match formula but getting syntax error

Comment: Dim OutputRange As Range
Set OutputRange = Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("A1:A50000")
OutputRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF($B1="customer account",INDEX('FEED DATA'!$D:$D,MATCH('RAW DATA FILE'!$B2,'FEED DATA'!$F:$F,0)),""),"")"

Comment: I have tried the below code. it is working but only for cell A1

Comment: Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(RC2=""customer account"",INDEX('FEED DATA'!C[3],match('RAW DATA FILE'!R[1]C2,'FEED DATA'!C[5],0)),""""),"""")"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A5"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A1:A5").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(RC2=""customer account"",INDEX('FEED DATA'!C4,match('RAW DATA FILE'!R[1]C2,'FEED DATA'!C6,0)),""""),"""")"
    Range("A1").Select